# Position image below bullet points in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am new to LaTeX and am currently busy making a slide presentation using beamer.

I have two bulletpoints and would like to place an image below them, such that the position of the left side of the image starts where the position of the bulletpoints starts. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      
  \usecolortheme{default} 
  \usefonttheme{default}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
  \graphicspath{ {bwinbe/} }
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{frame}{Chain Ladder}
\begin{itemize}
\item determenistic method to obtain reserve estimates using run-off triangles
\item starts from IBNR run-off triangle
\begin{figure}[]
\caption{Run-off triangle}
\includegraphics{triangle}
\end{figure}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have tried several options I found on the internet, but nothing seems to work. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While your question is quite clear and the code you posted is quite a nice starting point, it is normally preferred if the code is actually compilable, that is it should (in most cases) start giving the `\documentclass` and contain `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

It's an odd alignment, and you didn't specify anything in terms of the `\caption` placement.

You could place the image as a custom `\item` bullet:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Chain Ladder}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item determenistic method to obtain reserve estimates using run-off triangles
    \item starts from IBNR run-off triangle
    \item[\rlap{\includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image}}\hspace*{.5em}]
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `.5em` correction is roughly the space occupied by the bullet.